# Does using 'bind' when returning a function creates a closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, bind

my question regards the following example:

```
function inner(x){
  return x;
}

function outer(fn){
  var x = 'I just made a closure!!!'
  return  fn.bind(this, x)
}

var y = outer(inner)
    y()
```

when `y()` is invoked, does it has a closure over `x` because of `bind`? I'm confused because it does has access to an inner variable of the function `outer`, but it's nonetheless declared outside the scope of `outer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when y() is invoked, does it has a closure over x because of bind?

No, calling `bind` on a function returns a *bound function*. This bound function might however closure the function and the arguments, but that depends on the implementation. An implementation with a closure would look like:

```
 Function.prototype.bind = function(context, ...args) {
   const bound = this;
   return function(...args2) { // the closure
     bound.call(context, ...args, ...args2);
   };
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

> when y() is invoked, does it has a closure over x because of bind?

Not quite.

The value of `x` is passed as an argument to `bind`.

Consider this rough approximation of what an implementation of the `bind` function might look like:

```
function bind(this_value, first_argument_value) {
    return function () {
        // Call the original function with arguments and context
    }
}
```

It is `first_argument_value` that is closed over, not `x`.